# Slow 'Property Get' and 'Function' procedures

Tags: excel, vba

I have come across a nasty VBA bug that makes `Property Get` procedure calls really slow. This is most likely due to a recent Office update (I have Office365). It only affects Excel on 32 bit CPUs.

**The bug**

Consider a class called `Class1` with only the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Something() As Long: End Property
```

Basically, a single `Get` property that returns a zero.

When running the following code (in a standard .bas module):

```
Public Sub TestSpeed()
    Const iterations As Long = 10000
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As Double
    Dim coll As New Collection
    '
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To iterations
        coll.Add New Class1
        CallGet coll.Item(coll.Count)
    Next i
    Debug.Print iterations & " loops took " & Round(Timer - t, 3) & " seconds"
End Sub

Sub CallGet(ByVal c As Class1)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    v = c.Something
End Sub
```

I get a decent timing, as expected:

[image: i1]

However, if I add a bunch of other `Get` properties at the top of the one used in testing then things change. The updated `Class1` could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Something001() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something002() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something003() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something004() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something005() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something006() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something007() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something008() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something009() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something010() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something011() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something012() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something013() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something014() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something015() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something016() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something017() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something018() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something019() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something020() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something021() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something022() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something023() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something024() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something025() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something026() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something027() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something028() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something029() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something030() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something031() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something032() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something033() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something034() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something035() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something036() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something037() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something038() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something039() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something040() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something041() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something042() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something043() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something044() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something045() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something046() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something047() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something048() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something049() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something050() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something051() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something052() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something053() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something054() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something055() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something056() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something057() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something058() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something059() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something060() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something061() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something062() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something063() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something064() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something065() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something066() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something067() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something068() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something069() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something070() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something071() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something072() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something073() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something074() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something075() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something076() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something077() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something078() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something079() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something080() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something081() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something082() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something083() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something084() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something085() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something086() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something087() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something088() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something089() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something090() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something091() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something092() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something093() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something094() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something095() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something096() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something097() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something098() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something099() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something100() As Long: End Property
Public Property Get Something() As Long: End Property
```

The new timing is quite bad:
[image: i2]

**Notes**

Through more testing I found the following:

1. The time it takes to run the same `TestSpeed` method increases if I add more `Get` properties but only if I add them at the top of the one used. Of course, the time goes down if I remove some of the procedures.
2. It only affects my Excel 32 bit version. It works perfectly fine on Excel 64 bits and also perfectly fine in other apps like Word (on both 32 and 64 bits). Both my 32 and 64 bit Excel are version 2102 (Build 13801.21092) as in version 16.0.13801.21072
3. If I use late binding by replacing:
   `Sub CallGet(ByVal c As Class1)`
   with:
   `Sub CallGet(ByVal c As Object)`
   the bug is gone. Of course the late binding is a bit slower than early binding:
   [image: i3]

**Questions**

Can anyone reproduce the above behaviour?

Why is the above behaviour happening?

Besides waiting for Microsoft to fix this, is there anything else I could do to fix the issue?

**Edit #1**

As pointed out by @PeterT in his answer, the collections are really slow when used with lots of items and especially if items are retrieved by index.

Just to clarify, the issue above is still manifesting when using an array or a Scripting.Dictionary. For example the following code yields the same issue:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestSpeed()
    Const iterations As Long = 10000
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As Double
    Dim arr() As Class1: ReDim arr(1 To iterations)
    '
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To iterations
        Set arr(i) = New Class1
        CallGet arr(i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print iterations & " loops took " & Round(Timer - t, 3) & " seconds"
End Sub

Sub CallGet(ByVal c As Class1)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    v = c.Something
End Sub
```

Updated timings using array:

[image: i4]

**Edit #2**

Apparently, it does not matter if there are multiple `Property Get` procedures. Even if the class has only one property, the issue is still there, it's just I haven't noticed. By continuously pressing F5 to run the `TestSpeed` procedure, I got these results:

[image: i5]

Using late binding, I got these:

[image: i6]

**Edit #3**

When opening multiple Excel instances (ALT key down) the issue is gone for all the new instances but not for the initial instance. But that's only if I run the code in a new Excel file. If I simply open a saved Excel file that already has the code then the issue is still there for any instance.

Similarly, if I open the first Excel instance and run the code in a new unsaved file, then the issue is gone. However, when opening any saved file with same code then the issue manifests itself.

**Edit #4**

In fact, the issue is affecting all apps (Word, Outlook, PPT) but it only manifests itself if the file is saved and reopened. I only ran code in these  apps without saving thus wrongly assuming this is an Excel issue only.

I've also tested on AutoCAD 2019 and there is no issue even if loading a saved file. However, AutoCAD does not have the VBA code embedded in the file but rather saved as a '.dvb' separate project file.

Saving a macro-enabled file (ex. xlsb/xlsm) that has no code and then opening and adding the test code works perfectly fine and fast - no issue. However, if when saving the file, there is any code module (even if blank) then when opening the file the issue is there when adding the test code.

Comment: Hmm. I can't repro in 32-bit. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLuqX.png. Excel 365, version 16.0.13801.21072 (may be a few build(s) behind yours). I may be able to test later on a separate install.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @BigBen I just noticed that you have the exact same version as I do (updated the question as well). This makes me think that the issue might be related to other installed software.

Comment: Interesting - as in an addin? That would be rather annoying.

Comment: @BigBen Not sure. All of my co-workers have the same version and same issue so maybe an AddIn or some other software like antivirus.

Comment: @BigBen I've disabled all AddIns and even ran Excel in safe mode but still the issue is there. Absolutely annoying.

Comment: I, too, was unable to reproduce your problem, but I have an earlier version: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20240) 32-bit. I will see if I can update to your version and recheck.

Comment: With the latest version available to me:  Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20156) 32-bit , there is no measurable difference using your routine.  All runs are around 0.266 sec.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for confirming! I was afraid that the issue is related to the actual system configuration. Unfortunately it is my work machine and without admin rights I cannot even start Windows in safe mode to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: I take it with new use of an array v collection might be much faster with with a near empty class but only slightly with the 100 properties. I assume most of that time is creating the big classes with 'Set arr(i) = New Class' but 'CallGet arr(i)' is now negligible, is that right?

Comment: @PeterT Yes, the time is negligible on computers that do not have the issue but on the ones with the issue is still the same (as in over 2 seconds)

Comment: Could there be any debugging type app monitoring things. If an addin you can see which are loaded, but if something else might be worth asking your IT dept.

Comment: @PeterT I've disabled all AddIns but still the issue is present. Already contacted IT but that will take a while :) as in most companies

Comment: Only just noticed your 3rd observation in your notes above that late binding almost fixes the problem, that's curious to say the least! Could you test separately a) creating & populating the array, b) 10k calls of CallGet(ByVal c As Class1) passing each of the 10k classes, and similarly c) CallGetObj( ByVal c As Object). Also test if any difference with ByRef.

Comment: @PeterT Just added a print screen at the bottom of the last edit section. The 5th line is the benchmark and is what should really happen (almost negligible timing).

Comment: Very strange! Do those timings include both creating classes and calls to the CallGet routine in the same loop, like your original example? If not could you time them separately. They are distinct processes, it'd be interesting to see which (create & store v retrieve & use) one is slow.

Comment: @PeterT The only line that is slowing down things is the ```v = c.Something``` and that is only when there are multiple ```Property Get``` at the top of the class. Everything else (create instance, store instance in array, retrieve instance from array, stack frame for ```CallGet```) are negligible.

Comment: If it's only calling v = c.Something 10k times that's slow, is there any difference in calling the same class 10k times v. each of the 10k classes once (as in your original example)? If not, is creating 10k classes relevant? Also, is there any difference if instead of c.Somthing (the 101st property) you call the 1st property c.Somthing001 ?

Comment: @PeterT Calling the Get property on the same instance 10k times works fine. The problem is when the instances are different. Calling the 1st property is also fine. Calling the 2nd is slower, calling the 3rd is slower than the 2nd and so on. It gets slower depending on the position which is weird. In theory, it should have nothing to do with how many properties are defined above as the early binding should call with a precise offset in the vTable. The late binding works fine as IDispatch::Invoke calls the correct property regardless of the position. Absolutely weird.

Comment: @PeterT Just added an Edit #2 section. It seems that the number of properties does not matter. I did not think to repeateadly run the test procedure until now.

Comment: That makes more sense, but only slightly, it's still weird! I’m not sure testing with F5  helps but I’d expect even with 100k iterations ‘As Class’ to be very fast and same testing the first or 101st property. I’d expect ‘As Object’ to be noticeably slower testing the first property and very much slower the 101st property, though no difference with any of the results with qty of classes. The opposite of your results!  As you said 'As Object' would rely on IDispatch::Invoke but your slow results with ‘As Class’, hmm, a VTable is surely created but is it blocked... or is your system spooked!

Comment: @PeterT Found a new symptom. I fired up a new Excel instance by holding down ALT key. In the new instance the code runs super fast as expected with no issue. Meanwhile in the original instance it's still slow. Same with a 3rd instance - no problem. Any ideas? Thanks for replying to all my messages

Comment: @PeterT Added Edit #3 section

Comment: AIUI from your Edit#4, it's not running in a new instance that's relevant but running code in a file that's been saved and reopened. I can't think what's going on there but I'm interested to know, I have XL projects that may involve many 10k's of classes, I don't want to be hit with your problem without a solution:)

Comment: With your latest findings, does the issue still only occur in your and similar colleagues' x32 systems, or now can you repro' in other systems too and if so also x64. (I can't even with a saved file)

Comment: @PeterT The issue is still on all my colleagues laptops but not on VDI which is running the exact same Office version. I'm thinking it's some antivirus or background process that causes this but I do not have admin rights to run Windows in Safe Mode and IT cannot do that remotely until I return to London (although they could make an effort and test on one of their laptops - but they don't). Regardless, I will surely let you know when this gets fixed.

Comment: @PeterT Finally got to the bottom of the issue by speaking directly with a Microsoft engineer. Please see my answer - hopefully you won't have the issue but good to have it bookmarked

Comment: Thanks Christian for following up with this, definitely worth bookmarking! "Could there be any debugging type app monitoring things" (above) seems on the mark:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA code running speed decrease occurs when an Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) agent scans the code in real time.

The AMSI engine is part of Office since the year 2018:
[Office VBA + AMSI: Parting the veil on malicious macros - Microsoft Security Blog](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/09/12/office-vba-amsi-parting-the-veil-on-malicious-macros/)

The 'scans' are slowing down macros to an almost unusable stage and affect features like calling a `Function` or `Property Get` on an object. `Sub` does not seem affected but that would mean to return values as `ByRef` parameters.

For now I can safely say that [Carbon Black](https://www.vmware.com/products/carbon-black-cloud.html) is using this API and is causing macros to slow down on my company's computers. I use [Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.co.uk/) on my home computer but it does not cause any issues.

I suspect I've only experienced the issue now (Jan-2022) due to an upgrade of Carbon Black antivirus which now allows the software to hook into this feature.

The reason some of the PCs with Office 64 bits are unaffected might have to do with the antimalware software installed does not provide an engine for this architecture (yet).

**Solutions**

1. stop using the particular antivirus causing the issue - not really an option in my company
2. use the [Macro Runtime Scan Scope](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default_legacy.aspx#13838) policy which has a variety of options

> Note: This policy setting only applies to subscription versions of Office, such as Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise.

3. disable the AMSI engine [GPS: Disable commands (gpsearch.azurewebsites.net)](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default_legacy.aspx#11418)

Comment: So you set a bounty to a question that you already answered by yourself so that just more people look to the question? What is the idea?

Comment: @FunThomas As mentioned in the bounty description, just to raise awareness. It disrupted the work of 50+ people in my company for almost a month. No amount of googling helped until we spoke with a Microsoft engineer. Just imagine you encounter the same issue in 2 months - maybe you will remember seeing this and will be able to find my answer even if googling/searching does not find it. Maybe you even bookmark it just to be sure you can find it quickly.

Comment: I read the question is detail to understand your problem until I figured that you are not looking for an answer. Just image how many people like me read the question (without having any such problem), and how many persons think that the problem that they solved is really important. Either you or I misunderstood the reason to set a bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @FunThomas Apologies for wasting your time. I cannot remove the bounty so I added a bold first section to mention that I am not looking for an answer. My intentions were good but now I regret adding the bounty.

Comment: You suggested in #3 'disable the AMSI engine' - did that solve your issue as posted? If so why did that help? If not maybe in view of your 'As Object' worked so much better than early binding 'As Class' did you try [Allow VBA to load typelib references by path from untrusted intranet locations](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default_legacy.aspx#15118)  -

Comment: @PeterT I do not have admin rights so I cannot test any of the above without the IT department. I cannot add trusted locations nor cannot disable stuff. However, IT tested by disabling the Macro Runtime Scan Scope policy via registry and that solved it. They simply added the ```HKCU\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\common\security``` key and set it to disabled (0).

Comment: @PeterT Forgot to mention that #3 was suggested by the Microsoft engineer, so, it should work as well as #2. #1 is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Not sure how "...disable specific command bar buttons and menu items" helps here but if s/he says so.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your example in 2013-32 with an empty class v with the 100 properties, and only got a small difference in timings. I can only assume something related with your particular setup.

However I'd say your 0.45 sec is slow even in an old system, and the reason for that is your particular use of a large Collection. Two ways to improve -

1. Counter intuitively with large collections it's much faster to use Keys rather than Indexes to retrieve items, populating is only slightly slower with keys. Referencing col.Item(1) is fast but bigger indexes are progressively slower, seems internally the collection is looped to find the given index each time ...

   ```
    For i = 1 To iterations
       ' coll.Add New Class1
       ' CallGet coll.Item(coll.Count)
        coll.Add New Class1, CStr(i)
        CallGet coll.Item(CStr(i))
    Next i
   ```

I'd expect use of Key in this test to be a few times faster than your 0.45s. But in actual usage much better because most of the time here is populating the collection as it gets larger rather than retrieving items from the collection.

2. Instead of a collection use an array...

   ```
    ReDim arrClass(1 To iterations) As Class1
    For i = 1 To iterations
        Set arrClass(i) = New Class1
        Call CallGet(arrClass(CStr(i)))
    Next
   ```

This might be twice as fast again. Better though to test creating + storing the object references and retrieving them separately, they are distinct processes.

However no matter how much faster I appreciate the difference will be trivial until figuring the difference of your tests with an empty class and the 100 properties!

Comment: Thank you! My apologies for misleading you. I only used the collection randomly as I was trying to point out the issue. The same issue occurs with an array or a Scripting.Dictionary. As you said, I never retrieve items by index from a collection as that is really slow (linked list behind the scenes). I will update the question to remove any doubts for future readers.

Comment: No apologies needed. I realised use of collection wasn't the main cause of your particular issue, as I tried to make clear in my final remarks.

Comment: Thanks anyway! Within the same company the issue is not present on VDI having the same Excel version so by now I am pretty certain is a system issue rather than Excel/Office. +1

Comment: I seem to have been awarded your 100 bounty for my answer which was not really an answer, not sure that happened! Actually this is one of those rare posts that'd be worth 100 of my own points for the answer you got from your support engineer just to have in reserve:)

Comment: Yes, I've awarded the bounty to you. I only posted the bounty to draw attention that this issue is serious. The points would have been lost because of course I cannot award a bounty to myself. Regardless, I think your answer is also useful for other readers that do not know about how slow a Collection retrieves items by index. Again, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: In that case I accept it gracefully, thanks!