# Wrong Office version and Operating system in vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am running this code in VBA Excel 365 using Windows 11

```
Sub test()
Dim sBuild As String, sOP As String, sVersion As String

sBuild = Application.Build
sOP = Application.OperatingSystem
sVersion = Application.Version
MsgBox "Operating System " & sOP & " with Office version " & sVersion & " Build " & sBuild

End Sub
```

However, I get this message "Operating System Windows (64-bit) NT 10.00 with Office version 16.0 Build 15028"

The properties Application.Version and Application.OperatingSystem shows the same results as if I was running in Excel 2016 and using Windows 10.

Any suggestion to get the real Office and Windows version?

Thank you.

Manuel

Comment: What do you expect `Application.Version` to return for Excel 365?

Comment: See a possible example for versions 2016+ up to MS 365 at [Check the application version in modern office](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2019/02/11/check-the-application-version-in-modern-office/)

Comment: Further link you might be interested in: [Detect if dynamic arrays is enabled in Excel version with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842787/detect-if-dynamic-arrays-is-enabled-in-excel-version-with-vba/70843490#70843490)

Comment: These links were usefull. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link in the comment above works fine for Office ([Check the application version in modern office](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2019/02/11/check-the-application-version-in-modern-office/)).

I use this for Windows:

```
Function GetWindowsInfo() As String
  Dim oShell As Object
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim RegKeyProduct As String
  RegKeyProduct = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName"
  Dim ProductName As String
  ProductName = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyProduct)
  Dim VersionBuildNumbers(1 To 4) As Variant
  Dim RegKeyMajor As String
  RegKeyMajor = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentMajorVersionNumber"
  VersionBuildNumbers(1) = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyMajor)
  Dim RegKeyMinor As String
  RegKeyMinor = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentMinorVersionNumber"
  VersionBuildNumbers(2) = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyMinor)
  Dim RegKeyBuild As String
  RegKeyBuild = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber"
  VersionBuildNumbers(3) = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyBuild)
  If VersionBuildNumbers(3) >= 22000 Then
    ProductName = Replace(ProductName, "10", "11")
  End If
  Dim RegKeyUBR As String
  RegKeyUBR = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR"
  VersionBuildNumbers(4) = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyUBR)
  Dim BuildNumber As String
  BuildNumber = oShell.RegRead(RegKeyBuild) & "." & oShell.RegRead(RegKeyUBR)
  Dim Bitness As String
  Bitness = "32-bit"
  If Len(Environ("PROGRAMFILES(x86)")) Then Bitness = "64-bit"
  GetWindowsInfo = "Microsoft " & ProductName & " (" & Join(VersionBuildNumbers, ".") & ") " & Bitness
End Function
```

Comment: Thx for sharing; helpful as further addition to above links