# SQLite3 ODBC Driver + ADODB simple query extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance, sqlite, adodb

I use Excel VBA with SQLite3 ODBC driver obtained from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/
Both are 32 bits version on a Windows 10 computer.

A simple `Select` query on a single table with 16 columns and 200 rows takes approximately 200ms per row (I timed it).

**This is more than 30 seconds for a query that executes <30ms in SQLite3.**

I tried several cursorType , LockType , CursorLocation with no success

I tried Excel 2010 and Excel 365.

```
Sub TestSqlite()
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  cnn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Test.sqlite;"
  
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
  rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
  
  rs.Open "SELECT * from SimpleTable limit 20;", cnn
  
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  cnn.Close
  Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: This is not a general problem with using ADO, so it seems like the problem is likely related to the specific driver you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598025/slow-property-get-and-function-procedures/70861990#answer-70861990) problem with this stupid (pardon my French) Microsoft Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) feature, which sounds like a complete BS to me, and which grossly degrades performance of VBA7 DLL calls (I tried a few suggested on the Internet workarounds, but nothing worked for me). While when using ADO you don't call a DLL directly, eventually it calls the SQLiteODBC driver, and AMSI is the most likely culprit (together with all Windows built-in and activated by default security features). I have conducted a few [tests](https://pchemguy.github.io/DllTools/vba-dll-call) of my own last year, though in a slightly different environment. Even though I had disabled most security features, the result was pretty astonishing.